# Equivalent definitions of Bezout domain

Tags: ring-theory

We are in integral domain.
How can i prove equivalent of definitions for bezout domain.

Thats mean

sum of two principal ideals is principal ideal
vs
bezout identity holds.

Comment: First is for you to state, in your question, the two definitions needed: definition of Bezout domain, and definition of principal ideal [for the latter, are you working with two-sided, left- or right ideals?]

Comment: yes of course my mistake, we are in integral domain, so we have two-sided ideals. 

I have two definitions of bezout domain. 

1. is sum of two principal ideals is principal ideal
2. Domain, where bezout identity holds

and i wanna prove that is same

Comment: @SimonRitchie That is great context and should be edited into your question as soon as possible. We don't rely on comments to be permanent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(a),\ (b)$ are principal ideals. Bezout then gives $x,y$ such that $ax+by=\gcd(a,b).$ So if $d$ denotes $\gcd(a,b)$ we can get that the principal ideal $(d)$ is the same as $(a)+(b)$ by using the $x,y$ from Bezout. I'll leave the other direction of if and only if to you, as well as filling this sketch in a bit more.